# Where to hike near Indianapolis? Looking for rocky terrain/elevation changes

Tags: united-states, walking

I am looking for places to hike near Indianapolis that will be "exciting" for my feet.

Specifically, are there places that you recommend within ~50 miles of Indianapolis that have a lot of uneven or rocky terrain and/or elev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the good stuff is in southern IN - look into [McCormicks Creek SP](https://www.in.gov/dnr/parklake/2978.htm) near Spencer, [Morgan Monroe State Forest](https://www.in.gov/dnr/forestry/4816.htm) N of Bloomington, the [Deam Wilderness area](https://www.fs.usda.gov/recarea/hoosier/recarea/?recid=41554) on the SE side of Lake Monroe and [Brown County SP](https://www.in.gov/dnr/parklake/2988.htm) east of there. To the west of Indy are [Turkey Run](https://www.in.gov/dnr/parklake/2964.htm) and [Shades](https://www.in.gov/dnr/parklake/2970.htm) State Parks.

The [Knobstone Trail](https://www.in.gov/dnr/forestry/4275.htm) is outside your range further south, but is known for its elevation changes, but I still haven't been able to hike any of it. It is considered the most challenging trail in IN, but as you seem to be more interested in day-hiking you would need to pick a spot to out and back though there are 2 loops at the northern end you could do.

Nothing in IN is really rocky per se as you would find in true mountain ranges but you may find smaller sections in some areas that have lots of rocks and roots.

FWIW, there is a [group of hikers near Bloomington](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bloomington-hikers) that go on different weekly hikes every Saturday morning to areas similar to above though sometimes they are easier ones like rail trails.